# Ubuntu 18.04: failing to install rails after installing ruby with snap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, installation

I want to install Rails on my Ubuntu 18.04.

My installed ruby-version was 2.5.1 and since at least v.2.6 is recommended for Rails I uninstalled it like described [here](https://larrysanger.org/2019/01/how-to-delete-ruby-and-rails-and-other-gems-from-ubuntu-18-04/)
and then installed ruby v2.7 with

```
sudo snap install ruby --classic
```

like suggested [here](https://dev.to/gugacavalieri/install-latest-version-of-ruby-and-rails-using-snap-2d7e)

Now `ruby -v` shows me `ruby: 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]`

Then I run `sudo gem install rails` which runs without error and tells me that gems are installed.
When I run `rails -v` I get the message:

> Der Befehl 'rails' wurde nicht gefunden, kann aber installiert werden
> mit:
>
> sudo apt install ruby-railties

(command 'rails' cound not be found, but can be installed with `sudo apt install ruby-railties`)

Executing `apt install ruby-railties` proves to be useless - as expected, since a different package manager is used.

When I run `require 'rails'` in `irb` I get a "true".

Question: what am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use the version of Ruby provided by your OS. Use a Ruby version manager to compile and install Ruby from scratch. (and then you won't have to use sudo to install gems) Some options are available here: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#managers

Comment: Thanks, if no better solution comes up I'll have to do it. Tried RVM 2 or 3 years ago, got totally confused, hated it and switched to OS-ruby. So I was hoping to avoid the RVM.

Comment: Install RVM with `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.7`. Install Rails with `gem install rails`. Depending on your operating system you may need to install additional dependencies, like a compiler, but I can guarantee the three steps above are all that are needed to switch to RVM.

Comment: It's most likely that the snap Ruby is not in the path of root. Hence `sudo gem ...` will run under system Ruby, not the snap Ruby. If you want to run Ruby using snap, you either do not use `sudo`, which means gems will be installed in your home directory, or you need to fix the path lookup for root to also check for Ruby among snap binaries. This is my guess based on the information provided in your question. This is also the issue that newcomers to Ruby face most often. The `PATH` lookup of root is not the same as for user, hence confusion.

Comment: One vote for RVM you should use rvm, another thing when you are using `sudo` to install  then you have to use `sudo rails -v` as all installed stuff will needed sudo.

Comment: This Guide will help you on how to set up Ruby and Rails with RVM and Rbenv both

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04#ruby-rvm


Personally, I'll recommend the rvm as it helps you to easy by setting up gemsets for 
(different ruby and rails version) at the same time  
here is a guide link to that

https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,uninstall all ruby version do you have on your system .
example `sudo apt remove ruby`
After that install ruby by using snap :
`sudo snap install ruby --classic` then `gem install rails`.
Tape this in your terminal `whoami` ,copy the ouput and
finaly go open bashrc and put this like

```
alias rails="ruby/home/resultOfOuputOfWhoami/.gem/gems/railties-7.0.0/exe/rails"
```

That's it ,you got the latest version of rails